# angular ui-route set view for ancestor's brother

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm designing my UI-Router page. The *view-body* contains *navs-view*, and the *navs-view* is dynamic changed by route config, but I can't change the `toolBar` view. It can only work when I'm routing on view-body view.

I try to use `'toolBar@'`, but it does not work.

So how to change ancestor's brother's view?

[image]

The navs-view code:
[image]

config of nav
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Code snippets would be more easier to understand, than pictures,* but if I do ready your issue properly, both view targets:

```
<div ui-view="toolBar"></div>
<div ui-view ></div>
```

Are placed in one template. Most likely in parent template *(where parent is state `'main.navs'`)*. And then your views definition could/should use relative *(parent targeting)* names

```
views: {
  '' : {}
  'toolBar': {}
}
```

Or even absolute could be used *(but not good approach if relative is good enough)*

```
views: {
  '@main.navs' : {}
  'toolBar@main.navs': {}
}
```

And that means, that absolute is built from view target name and state name.

Only in case, that view target is in a grand parent we can use this definition

```
views: {
  '' : {}
  'toolBar@main': {}
}
```

Where `toolBar` is now part of `main` state view

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

> Behind the scenes, every view gets assigned an absolute name that follows a scheme of `viewname@statename`, where `viewname` is the name used in the view directive and state name is the state's absolute name, e.g. `contact.item`. You can also choose to write your view names in the absolute syntax.

Comment: hei, thanks, I was lost when dealing with too much views.....Thanks for let me awaken, Now I clear my thought, the key is @main   :D

Comment: Great to see that, sir! Enjoy amazing UI-Router ;)

Comment: It should work, as far as I remember. $stateChangeStart should be the way... But I would suggest, create new question, deeply (but briefly;) describe the use case, show some code and you'll get your answer...